# Abusing Notations: Is it unacceptable to write $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f(t) = \infty$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, notation, divergence-operator

Suppose $f:[0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(t)$ is a function that diverges as $t \to \infty$ i.e. $f(t) = e^{t}$

It is very common to see people (mainly beginning math students) write

$\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f(t) = \infty$

I don't think this is good practice, since we are equating something to something else that is not a number. What would be a better way to write this?

I would personally write:

$f(t) \to \infty$, as $t \to \infty$

Is it okay to also write

$\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f(t) \to \infty$

Comment: Some people write that but it's an abuse of notation. A correct way to write it would be to simply write that the limit doesn't exist or that $f(t) \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: If your function grows arbitrarily large as $t \to \infty$, you can make the "limit equals $\infty$" part precise see e.g. Terence Tao's measure theory book: https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf

Comment: In strict limit laws, infinity is not an answer to a limit. However, if we want to evaluate a limit as $arctane^x$ where x goes to inifnity, it is important to know that $e^x$ is going to infinity upon which the arctan does have a finite limit!. Also, sometimes we write infinity as an answer to explain curve behavior. But again, be careful when applying limit laws in such a situation...

Comment: To me this notation is completely correct. Infinity is not a number, just a symbol, but it doesnt matter. We can add these symbols to the real line so I dont see any problem (the extended real line is defined as $\Bbb {\bar R}=\Bbb R\cup \{-\infty,+\infty\}$).

Comment: As a professional mathematician, I can report that the use of $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)=\infty$ is not at all limited to "mainly beginning math students".

Comment: I think it's acceptable if we accept that the clause "= $\infty$" means "= when extended to the extended real number system".  If it's good enough for walter rudin then it is good enough for me.

Comment: @Ed_4434 But the limit does indeed exist (atleast in the wide-sense). Either ways, this notation is common and acceptable when trying to say that *$\forall M \in \mathbb{R}$ . $\exists x_M$ s.t. $x>x_M$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(x)>M$ *.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> It is very common to see people (mainly beginning math students) write
>
> $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f(t) = \infty$

This is fine, and can be made completely rigorous.
See [extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line).

Of course it could still be  used in a wrong way but to write $\lim_{t \to \infty}  t^6 - 67 = \infty$ is perfectly correct.

> I would personally write:
>
> $f(t) \to \infty$, as $t \to \infty$

That's also fine. I would consider it as "synonym" of the above.

> Is it okay to also write
>
> $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f(t) \to \infty$

No, this is a strange mix of notations. The limit, when it exists, is some fixed 'thing' (a real number or a 'symbol' $\infty$ or maybe $-\infty$ or still something else). In any case, the limit does not approach anything it *is (equal to) something* (or does not exist).

Answer (score 6):

The point I want to emphasize here is: *$\lim f(t)=\infty$ is a notation we use to stand for some specific behavior of a function; it is not declaring the equality of two numbers.*

The math community has decided over time to use the notation $\lim f(t)=\infty$. In a parallel universe, parallel-we might have decided to use some different notation; but for us, this is the standard notation, and is therefore correct *by definition*. I believe we have chosen to use this notation because the "ambiguity" with the standard meaning of the equals sign, on balance, helps our understanding more than it misleads us. But that is a judgment call, not a mathematical fact.

While one can talk about extended real number lines, nonstandard analysis, etc., I don't think they're relevant to the real discussion here. In standard calculus, we use the notation $\lim f(t)=\infty$, but that *doesn't* mean that infinity is a number. That's simply not what the notation means (according to our standard conventions). Indeed, if I see that notation, I would not say that the limit exists—I would say that the limit fails to exist, in a very specific way (for example, unlike the ways in rtybase's answer). When a function "diverges to infinity", that means the limit doesn't exist, but also that the manner of divergence is a specific one that we recognize as important enough to have given it its own notation.

(I've specifically avoided the subscripts on the limits above, because the discussion applies just as well to $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to3}$ and so on.)

Comment: Nonstandard analysis is orthogonal. The "extended real number line" is, as I assume you know well,  a topological  space whose elements are the real number  and two additional elements. So while the notation does not mean that $\infty$ is "a number," the limit is equal to this element of that topological space (with respect to the topology of that space). There'd also be no mystery about these elements if one just were to draw the real line in a different way. Draw it like an  open semicircle now add the two points to have closed semicircle. In the complex numbers it is even more striking.

Comment: I agree with everything you say. I simply don't think it's relevant to a discussion of what this notation means to the majority of people who use it (i.e., first year calculus students who don't know what "topology" even means).

Comment: Possibly. Although, the extended real line is subject of some first year courses (mine for instance, both as student and teacher). The abstract notion topology is perhaps a distraction it is not really needed; limit/continuity via neighborhoods is rather needed though. This might not be common in calculus course; I really do not know, different system.

Answer (score 5):

Just an addition to @quid's answer, it is actually not unusual to see such notations and definitions in many analysis books (and school manuals) including [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Infinite_limits). These definitions are rigorous and should not be confused with divergence though, e.g. $f(x)=x \cdot \sin{x}$ and $x_n=\pi \cdot n$, $y_n=\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\cdot \pi$ and $z_n=\frac{\pi}{2} + (2n+1)\cdot \pi$.

Comment: Good point to stress that it is not any form of divergence that can be denoted in this way. This what I had in mind with "use in a wrong way" but it is good to have it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Another addition to @quid's answer: as said, $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)=\infty$ can be properly defined with the extended real number line. But you can also make another choice, of not writing what does not exist: for instance, you don't write $\frac{3}{0}$ because this number does not exist, so you can choose not to write $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\sin(x)$ because $x\sin(x)$ has no limit in $\infty$, or $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2\ \mathrm{d}x$, same for $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sqrt{i}$. So even if $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)=\infty$ is not incorrect, I would personally prefer something else, such as the alternatives proposed.

Comment: For one of your examples, $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sqrt i$ does actually diverge to $\infty$.